# Remove Blank Space between fields

Tags: shell, sed, awk, tr

I have more than 400,000 fields in a `input.txt` separated by blank spaces.
For example `0 2 1 1 1 2` repeated 400,000 times.

I need to put them together like `021112`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways you could do this, the most concise would be to use `tr` to delete all spaces:

```
tr -d ' ' < file > outfile
```

Alternatively with `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/ //g' file
```

Warning: the `sed` solution overwrites the original file with the changes.

Since your asked about `awk` the general solution would be to set a blank `OFS` and force a rebuild with `$1=$1` but it's not really as elegant as the first two solutions:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS= file > outfile
```

Comment: No problem. You should accept this answer *(unless a better one comes along)* by clicking the tick mark next to it. This will show your question as solved.

Comment: In case there are tabs, maybe use `s/[[:space:]]//g` instead of `s/ //g` (or `tr -d '[:space:]'`)